# SoftHSMv2 - How to make created objects survive between sessions?

Tags: softhsm

1. I open a session
2. I create an AES key with a label by using C_CreateObject
3. I can lookup the created object by label by using C_FindObjects.
4. I close the session.
5. I open a new session.
6. I can no longer lookup the created object by label using C_FindObjects.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Two possibilities come to my mind:

1. Per [PKCS#11 2.40](http://docs.oasis-open.org/pkcs11/pkcs11-base/v2.40/os/pkcs11-base-v2.40-os.html),

> Only session objects can be created during a read-only session

Therefore the session of `C_CreateObject` needs to have been opened with the `flags` argument set to `CKF_SERIAL_SESSION | CKF_RW_SESSION` .

2. The `pTemplate` argment to `C_CreateObject` needs to include the `CKA_TOKEN` attribute so that the newly created key would be a "token object" rather than a "session object".

In PKCS#11, a token object is persistent across sessions whereas a session object is ephemeral and would get dropped once the session is closed.

Hope this helps.